# Creating a List and Removing Duplicates in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a list in Python using .split. My code splits the user's input into a list. I am wondering on how I can stop the program printing duplicates of the word in the sentence. My code is currently this:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence").lower()
sentencesplit = sentence.split()
print(sentencesplit)
```

When I enter "Run run Forrest run" it will return:

```
['run', 'run', 'Forrest', 'run']
```

But I want it to return only run and Forrest, I want it to only list the same word once. Does anyone know a way of doing this? I need to keep the order, so the question's similar to this do not help me, so don't mark this a duplicate, just leave and move on with your life.

Thanks, Izaak

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. Please actually read through that page.

Comment: No its not as I want to keep the order

Comment: Yes it is. That question has _twenty-four answers_, and the _very second one_ provides a solution that maintains the original ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `set`:

```
list(set(sentencesplit))
```

Comment: if order of the words is not important..

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist = [word for word in mylist if mylist.count(word) == 1]
```

Comment: Missing a final `]`.

Comment: While this is a valid answer, it is very inefficient compared to the alternatives

Comment: the proposed alternatives don't ignore order of words